# Back EMF protection of a bi-directional inductive load

Tags: diodes, motor, h-bridge, protection, back-emf

I have been researching this subject for some time now and I found three ways to deal with this issue but I can't make up my mind on which one is the best for my application.

I have a high torque 12V 5A DC motor that runs bi-directionally using an H-bridge.  After turning the motor off, it still moves for at least 3 seconds which results in inaccuracies (high accuracy and instant response are highly crucial to my project.) I was thinking of putting a mechanical break in my system to stop it from moving but that's not quite possible, so I want to use a back EMF suppression system that can help with this issue and also protect my component and circuits. The three possible solutions that I found online:

1. Ising MOV across motors leads (their life expectancy and reliability are questionable based on what I found online)

2. Using a bridge rectifier and connect motor leads to the AC input and the other two pins to the ground and 12V
3. Using two Zener diodes with their anodes connected to each other

While researching the second solution, I came across something about noise being transmitted into my power and ground rail which I know very little about but it does seem like something I need to avoid.

Any feedback or suggestion on which of the three I should use or any other solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If precision is paramount, have you considered adding position sensor (e.g. a sin/cos encoder)? Or one of these sensors that give you the current rotor angle in degrees or even fraction of degrees via a digital interface?

Comment: In general the motor continues to run due to inertia, having it stop abruptly (mechanically) when you no longer need it to turn is not a good idea. That inertia has to go somewhere and that would cause a jolt; whether you'd stop it mechanically or electrically doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Your second solution is used very common, and is often inside (smaller) driver chips. What is your power supply? Can't it absorb the current? The enegry has to go somewhere, either electrically or mechanically...

Comment: Bidirectional TVS diodes  (or two unidirectional TVS diodes back-to-back) do something similar to your #3. But the actual solution to your problem is to use a better, smarter form of motor control that doesn't just involve killing the power when you want the motor to stop.

Comment: @anrieff i am utilizing a rotary encoder to get the position. I'm even using a PID control which made it a lot better but didn't solve the problem completely. hence the delay between achieving the exact position and executing the next motion command can be a few seconds which is absolutely unacceptable

Comment: Continue to work on that PID algorithm and augment it if need be. That's where your solution is, such as adding feed forward or enabling the algorithm to use your H-bridge actively brake your motor (and beefing up your H-bridge to handle things if necessary).

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen im using a 200W pc power supply but that's not nearly enough as I'm using 8 of those motors! but abut sol #2, do your think it'll have an instantaneous reaction?

Comment: @DKNguyen my motor driver can handle up to 30A and I'm using an avr micro as my controller. i need a movement with constant speed and accurate positioning (2 PIDs)and my programming skill aren't strong enough to make my controller better so i need an electrical solution!

Comment: Sarah, Try to define what you want for each parameter, a,v,x ,(max) and (tolerance)  then current needed for a(max) and current available.  BEMF current reduces to 0 , What you want is constant a (max) , then constant v (max) then constant -a (max) then switch to velocity mode control then switch to position mode control so that V=0 at x error=0 with no overshoot.  Thus 3 state control all 1st order error is OK but position error can be tuned when in Position error mode control for PES=0.  If you want fastest brake, you would need to reverse  voltage with PWM and control current = trapezoid

Comment: "After turning the motor off, it still moves for at least 3 seconds". If you have a encoder feedback and a PID controller, you should not "turn the motor off", but rather give the PID an appropriate input to stop the motor at a given  point. But before that, even, you should give the PID an appropriate input to slow the motor down. The PID should get a trapezoidal input to drive the motor from "location" A to "location" B. With appropriate tuning of the PID, you can get 1) virtually no overshoot, 2) fine control of the stopping point.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 it makes sense thanks! now i just have to figure out how to code it!

Comment: Some RPi shields have open source shields with Servo uploads that give you a windows GUI for all these parameters to program.  IDK so look around.  Is it 2 phase or 3 BLDC or just DC?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 i have 8 dc motors, 1 stepper, and 1 servo. i have designed separate PCBs to precisely control each motor and talk to my main  board (Rpi) with can protocol. i need to write my own Rpi program to control everything so that won't help me that much, thanks tho!

Comment: just remember to use current feedback for acceleration control and velocity feedback for velocity control then PES for position control rather than PID on just position encoder